# Bash: Turning each item in an array into a command argument with a flag

Tags: bash

Suppose we have the array `FOO=("hello world" "xyzzy")`. We want to run the `thing` tool, with each element of `$FOO` passed as a separate `-Z` flag, resulting in the command:

```
thing -Z "hello world" -Z "xyzzy"
```

These do not work:

```
# Equivalent to `thing "-Z hello world" "-Z xyzzy"`
thing "${FOO[@]/#/-Z }"

# Equivalent to `thing "-Z hello world -Z xyzzy"`
thing "${FOO[*]/#/-Z }"

# Equivalent to `thing -Z hello world -Z xyzzy`
thing ${FOO[@]/#/-Z }

# Equivalent to `thing -Z hello world -Z xyzzy`
thing ${FOO[*]/#/-Z }
```

What I can do is insert a `-Z` in between every element of the array:

```
FOO2=()
for x in "${FOO[@]}"; do FOO2+=("-Z" "$x"); done
thing "${FOO2[@]}"
```

Is there a way to do it that doesn't require an explicit loop and a copy of the array?

Comment: Not making a firm pronouncement, but I'll note that the explicit loop is what I do.

Comment: If the tool allows the argument to be directly attached to `-Z` (i.e. `thing "-Zhello world" "-Zxyzzy"`), then you can use `thing "${FOO[@]/#/-Z}"`. Otherwise, I think you need to use a loop.

Comment: I like @GordonDavisson's suggestion because a lot of GNU style tools will support this through their long options, e.g. `sed -e foo -e bar` => `sed --expression=foo --expression=bar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Creating A New Array With `bash` ≥ 4.4

You could print the array using null byte delimiters (`\0`), insert `-Z\0` in front of every entry, and then read the result as an array again:

The following solution requires `bash` ≥ 4.4 because of `mapfile -d`. For an alternative, see the hack at the end of this answer.

```
processargs() {
   (( "$#" )) && printf -- '-Z\0%s\0' "$@"
}
array=('' 1 ' x y ' $'multiline\ntext')
mapfile -d '' arrayWithZ < <(processargs "${array[@]}")
```

For testing we use the built-in `declare -p` to print all entries of the result array `arrayWithZ` (linebreaks inserted manually for better readability).

```
$ declare -p arrayWithZ
declare -a arrayWithZ=(
  [0]="-Z"
  [1]=""
  [2]="-Z"
  [3]="1"
  [4]="-Z"
  [5]=" x y "
  [6]="-Z"
  [7]=$'multiline\ntext'
)
```

For the empty array we do not insert any `-Z`. If `array=()` then `arrayWithZ=()`.

## Using `eval`, Especially For `bash` < 4.4

If you don't need the explicit array `arrayWithZ` then you can use the following hack. Even though `eval` should be safe in this case I would advice against using it -- maybe I did oversee something. However this hack might be useful when you are stuck with `bash` < 4.4 since `mapfile -d` is not required anymore.

```
processargs() {
   (( "$#" )) && printf -- '-Z %q ' "$@"
}
array=('' 1 ' x y ' $'multiline\ntext')
eval "yourCommand $(processargs "${array[@]}")"
```

Comment: You could use `printf -- '-Z\0%s\0' "$@"` to avoid going via `sed`, but this is really just a more convoluted way of creating a copy of the array with the extra arguments intercalated.

Comment: @thatotherguy Nice! That's not only shorter but also runs on BSD. I edited my answer according to your suggestion.